# Is is possible to keep working on MBE, particle accelerators after in-body metal implants?

Tags: changing-fields, health

I am about to undergo surgery after which I will end up with small titanium rods in my body. I wanted to ask if i would be able to continue working in my chosen field (which involves MBE (molecular beam epitaxy) and working with other devices with strong magnets). Wondering if I should switch my research field to a non-magnetic environment.

I have asked my doctor who says that it's a big no for pacemakers, but it should be okay if i don't spend too much time near those machines.

Wanted to ask if any one knows of cases, or has experienced anything like this?

Comment: Ask your doctor what "too much" time means. Not strangers on the Internet who don't know your medical history.

Comment: This isn't enough for an answer (it's not precisely relevant, and kind of a side-answer), but I had some titanium plates and screws put inside me which were later removed once the bone was sufficiently healed as to be able to withstand daily movement without them. It took about 1.5 years. This isn't ideal, but at least it's an option, although it may take some time and be dependent upon your recovery.

Comment: @ff524 edited to remove that ambiguity. I was only asking for experience. The question about time was rhetorical. Sorry abt that.

Comment: @lafemmecosmique thanks for sharing. this thing is going to become a part of me, will be inside forever.

Comment: You shouldn't be allowed to work in a magnet lab if you don't know the answer to this question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I would like to point out that it is concerned with switching topics due to health issues!

Comment: Also, titanium is not ferromagnetic, so you should even be able to go into an MRI.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I'm starting next year. That's why wanted to if somebody in this community has any experience with this

Comment: 1) “Does anybody have experience with this?” is a poll and not a good question for any Stack Exchange. 2) Right now, it is unclear what *this* is: Changing fields, working in a magnetic environment with titanium implants or something else entirely. 3) @AnonymousPhysicist was remarking on the fact that there should not be a problem in the first place.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft This is a yes/no question with a correct answer.  It's not a poll.

Comment: "titanium is not ferromagnetic, so you should even be able to go into an MR"  Paramagnetic materials also experience magnetic forces.  This is dangerous advice.  Also, it might be an alloy.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: Titanium is used to make surgical instruments for MRI operating rooms. Patients with titanium implants can go into MRIs. Yes, there are fringe cases such as if your implant acts as a coil or is ferromagnetic due to being an alloy, hence “should”. However, in the vast majority of cases falling under the asker’s description (“small titanium rods in my body”), there should not be a problem. Should the asker fall under these fringe cases, there is no way to answer this without knowing further details (and the question would be off-topic anyway).

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist: There is only one way I can think of interpreting “Wanted to ask if any one knows of cases, or has experienced anything like this?” as a yes/no question and in that case the answer is the maximally unhelpful: “Yes, somebody knows of such cases and somebody has experienced something like this.”

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for specific medical advice in a health-critical situation, which should be directed to medical and physics professionals with full knowledge of the individual case.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a paramagnetic body implant, you must never enter a strong magnetic field.  You should consult with your institution's safety department about establishing appropriate controls, procedures, and permissible exposures.  Probably you can continue to work in a magnet lab, but only when the magnet is off.  An appropriate interlock should be used.

[Magnet injuries](http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJM200109273451316)